# Why does update-mime-database complain about uri/rtspt and other unusual types?

Tags: apt, aptitude, updates, mime-type

When running `update-mime-database` - usually automatically launched by `apt-get` - why do I reliably get complaints like:

```
Unknown media type in type 'all/all'
Unknown media type in type 'all/allfiles'
Unknown media type in type 'uri/mms'
Unknown media type in type 'uri/mmst'
Unknown media type in type 'uri/mmsu'
Unknown media type in type 'uri/pnm'
Unknown media type in type 'uri/rtspt'
Unknown media type in type 'uri/rtspu'
Unknown media type in type 'fonts/package'
Unknown media type in type 'interface/x-winamp-skin'
```

It doesn't seem to be hurting anything, but chronic errors during updates risk obscuring an error that I do care about.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Actually you can fix it simply by doing

```
sudo rm /usr/share/mime/packages/kde.xml 
sudo update-mime-database /usr/share/mime
```

Here is [a quote from Ana Guerrero in 2008](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=469833#27) so you'd think it would be fixed by now.

> Those fake mimetypes are installed by `kdelibs` with the file
>   `/usr/share/mime/packages/kde.xml` since long time ago. They are kept in
>   kde4libs.
>
> In a recent version, `update-mime-database` became verbose about this unknown
>   types, and that is why you get this error when you update stuff and then
>   `update-mime-database` is run.
>   It is unlikely to be changed.

Comment: Still needed in 15.10 ;-(  I have followed this, forgot how to do it, searched, found it, and did it again.  lather rinse repeat.  Each time, although I did not remember where the files and what the commands were, I found this post and have visited and used it 3 times (stats from google search on chrome).  I used this search string, and add it here so that it rises from second to first ([How to remove warnings like `Unknown media type](http://askubuntu.com/questions/39852/how-to-remove-warnings-like-unknown-media-type) in the set of answers. ubuntu mime-types all/all unknown media type

Comment: What are the consequences of removing the file? Because I don't think kde installs that file without a reason? You may lose the mime recongnization

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. but it doesnt work for 14.04

Answer (score 5):

That's a problem with `update-mime-database` and the MIME standard itself. Originally it was supposed to be extensible. But the IETF dumbed it down, and no new major mime types are registered (application/* is used as undifferentiated catch-all). The reasoning/surmise behind that being, that few tools are designed to work correctly with new MIME types.

Now update-mime-database at least doesn't fall over when it sees pseudo classifiers like uri/ and fonts/ or interface/. So I assume it only complains because other apps might actually trip over them. `strings` gave me following list of probably built-in list of "safe" MIME types:

- text
- application
- image
- audio
- inode
- video
- message
- model
- multipart
- x-content
- x-epoc

Meaning it would nag over any other `x-` or `x.` and `vnd.` or `prs.` major mime types. Curiously `inode/` is anything but an official media type.

Comment: Thanks for this valuable comment. It's very useful to know that custom-named mimetypes won't work. Tried creating a mimetype named 'comprovante/biblioteca' and that's why it wasn't working on recent Ubuntu / Linux Mint versions.

Answer (score 2):

It appears that there are a pile of KDE libraries that bring in these otherwise Gnome unfriendly mime-type definitions. In my case, the libraries were added as dependencies to a KDE application package that I later uninstalled.

To remove the pile of KDE libraries and their associated /usr/share/mime entries, I used:

```
sudo apt-get purge kdelibs-bin kdelibs-data 
sudo apt-get autoremove --purge
sudo update-mime-database /usr/share/mime
```

Do be careful that the first command does not force removal of a package you need before you confirm the removal. Getting rid of kdelibs-bin will then make a large set of packages unneeded and ready for autoremove.

I found the basis for this fix in an [old bug report for Intrepid Ibex](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/268956).

Answer (score 0):

**Backup your `/usr/share/mime` directory, just in case.**

I solved it by removing all the `.xml` files on `/usr/share/mime` directory then run the update command

```
cp -R /usr/share/mime /usr/share/mime_back
find  /usr/share/mime -name *.xml -exec rm -rfv {} +    
update-mime-database /usr/share/mime
```

https://askubuntu.com/a/299482/789190.

https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=469833