# How to remove warnings like `Unknown media type ...`

Tags: aptitude

Each time `apt-get` tries to process triggers for shared-mime-info, it reports warnings like:

```
...
Processing triggers for shared-mime-info...
Unknown media type in type 'all/all'
Unknown media type in type 'all/allfiles'
Unknown media type in type 'uri/mms'
Unknown media type in type 'uri/mmst'
Unknown media type in type 'uri/mmsu'
Unknown media type in type 'uri/pnm'
Unknown media type in type 'uri/rtspt'
Unknown media type in type 'uri/rtspu'
Unknown media type in type 'interface/x-winamp-skin'
```

I've checked `/usr/share/mime-info` but doesn't see any of them:

```
/usr/share/mime-info$ grep 'url/rtspu' *
(Got nothing)
```

So, how to clean up my system so it won't report these unknown media types?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This was discussed in [Why does update-mime-database complain about uri/rtspt and other unusual types?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18806/why-does-update-mime-database-complain-about-uri-rtspt-and-other-unusual-types)
It is caused by kde.xml and they have not fixed it yet. Here is a [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/shared-mime-info/+bug/289592).

Also it's `uri/rtspu`, not `url/rtspu` you should be grepping.

Answer (score 45):

Backup the file that is causing the errors and update the systems mime database:

```
sudo mv -vi /usr/share/mime/packages/kde.xml /usr/share/mime/packages/kde.xml.bak
sudo update-mime-database /usr/share/mime
```

This should fix the warnings.

Comment: What are the (other) consequences of removing this file?

Comment: What harm could this do?

Comment: If concerned about the consequences, instead of removing kde.xml, move it to kde.xml.bak and you'll have a backup. Thus far I've had no adverse effects with this approach. another method would be to edit the file and remove the fake mime types as discussed at http://mapopa.blogspot.com/2011/01/fixing-unknown-media-type-in-type.html

Answer (score 10):

You should check `/usr/share/mime/packages` for the specific xml that contains the phrase you get .

For example, my problem was `Unknown media type in type 'chemical/......`
I found the file `/usr/share/mime/packages/chemical-mime-data.xml`.

Using `cat` on the file showed me that the package was the same `chemical-mime-data V 0.94`

So I ran:

```
sudo apt-get remove chemical-mime-data
```

Answer (score 6):

The bug stems from KDE, and has not been fixed since 2008:

- https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=303627
- https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=250924
- https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=469833
- https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/shared-mime-info/+bug/289592