# LibreOffice won't start?

Tags: libreoffice, dependencies, openoffice.org

Every time I click LibreOffice in the menu, it returns this error:

> Failed to execute command "libreoffice --writer %U".Failed to execute
>   child process "libreoffice" (No such file or directory)

When installing LibreOffice, it returns this error:

> The following packages have unmet dependencies:  libreoffice-core :
>   Depends: libreoffice-common (> 1:3.4.5) but it is not going to be
>   installed  libreoffice-java-common : Depends: libreoffice-common but
>   it is not going to be installed E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f
>   install' with no packages (or specify a solution).

I tried to run 'apt-get -f' but it doesn't solve the issue. **Any one know what to do?**

If its worth mentioning, I tried installing open office, when running 'apt-get -f' it says:

> dpkg: error processing
>   /var/cache/apt/archives/libreoffice-common_1%3a3.4.5-0ubuntu1~ppa1_all.deb
>   (--unpack):  trying to overwrite
>   '/usr/share/mime/packages/openoffice.org.xml', which is also in
>   package openoffice.org-debian-menus 3.3-9556 No apport report written
>   because MaxReports is reached already

Comment: Did you try `sudo apt-get -f install`? What is the error message, or is there none?

Comment: Here is part of the output of sudo apt-get -f install:

Unknown media type in type 'all/all'
Unknown media type in type 'all/allfiles'
Unknown media type in type 'uri/mms'
Unknown media type in type 'uri/mmst'
Unknown media type in type 'uri/mmsu'
Unknown media type in type 'uri/pnm'
Unknown media type in type 'uri/rtspt'
Unknown media type in type 'uri/rtspu'
Unknown media type in type 'interface/x-winamp-skin'
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libreoffice-common_1%3a3.4.5-0ubuntu1~ppa1_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Comment: Are you using kde? 
Something has become corrupted. Try removing the downloaded packages (`sudo apt-get clean` , and a `sudo apt-get autoclean` wouldn't hurt. Then try installing again. If that doesn't work have a look at http://askubuntu.com/questions/39852/how-to-remove-warnings-like-unknown-media-type and http://askubuntu.com/questions/81263/how-to-i-fix-software-center-after-installing-the-linux-mint-mate-desktop

Comment: Possible duplicate of [dpkg error: "trying to overwrite file, which is also in..."](https://askubuntu.com/questions/176121/dpkg-error-trying-to-overwrite-file-which-is-also-in)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try to install Libre office downloaded from website. Follow the README files in directories for install. It works very well on my Lucid Desktop and automatically integrates with OS GUI.

Comment: Since LibreOffice 3.5 up-to-date and stable LibreOffice versions are available at the LibreOffice ppa: https://launchpad.net/~libreoffice/+archive/ppa/ please do not recommend to install upstream packages as the better integrated packages from the PPA are now available on the same day.

Comment: Well, this post is quite old as You can notice...

Comment: And still, the problem was with dependencies, so I think that adding another repos wouldn't help anyways. Regards :)

Answer (score 0):

"openoffice.org-debian-menus" is not a supported Ubuntu package: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+search?text=openoffice.org-debian-menus

You likely installed .deb-files from some third party or PPA and did not cleanly remove those. Do a `sudo apt-get purge openoffice.org-debian-menus` (and repeat for other leftovers).

Comment: ~$ sudo apt-get purge openoffice.org-debian-menus
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libreoffice-core : Depends: libreoffice-common (> 1:3.4.5) but it is not going to be installed
 libreoffice-java-common : Depends: libreoffice-common but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).

Comment: Your system state seems to be messed up pretty bad. In this case please also remove libreoffice-core (dpkg --remove libreoffice-core) and do the same with any other package apt/dpkg complain about before trying to install again.