# App don't removed and run after apt purege ( App must be romeved!!!)

Tags: apt, package-management

I want to reinstall vlc app in Ubuntu and i have tried reinstall option form synaptic app. but my problem by vlc don't solved .
so i tried to completely remove it form my PC and again install it. 
so i have run this apt purge and Get this output:

```
so@so-notebook:~$ sudo apt-get purge vlc
[sudo] password for so: 
Sorry, try again.
[sudo] password for so: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package 'vlc' is not installed, so not removed
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  biber catdoc dvdauthor kactivities-bin kbibtex-data kde-cli-tools-data kded5
  kdenlive-data kpackagetool5 libaribb24-0 libautovivification-perl
  libbasicusageenvironment1 libbtparse2 libbusiness-isbn-data-perl
  libbusiness-isbn-perl libbusiness-ismn-perl libbusiness-issn-perl libcddb2
  libclass-factory-util-perl libclass-inspector-perl libclass-singleton-perl
  libdata-compare-perl libdata-uniqid-perl libdate-simple-perl
  libdatetime-calendar-julian-perl libdatetime-format-builder-perl
  libdatetime-format-strptime-perl libdatetime-locale-perl libdatetime-perl
  libdatetime-timezone-perl libdbusmenu-qt5-2 libdvbpsi10
  libencode-eucjpms-perl libencode-jis2k-perl libepub0 libfakekey0
  libfile-find-rule-perl libfile-sharedir-perl libfile-slurper-perl
  libgroupsock8 libhfstospell9 libipc-run3-perl libkf5activities5
  libkf5attica5 libkf5bookmarks-data libkf5bookmarks5 libkf5completion-data
  libkf5completion5 libkf5crash5 libkf5dbusaddons-bin libkf5dbusaddons-data
  libkf5dbusaddons5 libkf5declarative-data libkf5doctools5
  libkf5filemetadata-bin libkf5filemetadata-data libkf5filemetadata3
  libkf5globalaccel-bin libkf5globalaccel-data libkf5globalaccel5
  libkf5globalaccelprivate5 libkf5jobwidgets-data libkf5jobwidgets5
  libkf5kcmutils-data libkf5kiocore5 libkf5kiofilewidgets5 libkf5kiontlm5
  libkf5kiowidgets5 libkf5kirigami2-5 libkf5newstuff-data
  libkf5notifications-data libkf5notifyconfig-data libkf5package-data
  libkf5package5 libkf5parts-data libkf5pty-data libkf5pty5 libkf5service-bin
  libkf5service-data libkf5service5 libkf5solid5 libkf5solid5-data
  libkf5sonnet5-data libkf5sonnetcore5 libkf5sonnetui5 libkf5su-bin
  libkf5su-data libkf5su5 libkf5textwidgets-data libkf5textwidgets5
  libkf5wallet-data libkf5xmlgui-bin libkf5xmlgui-data libkf5xmlgui5
  liblingua-translit-perl liblist-allutils-perl liblist-someutils-perl
  liblist-utilsby-perl liblivemedia62 libmicrodns0 libnfs11
  libnumber-compare-perl libopenmpt-modplug1
  libpackage-deprecationmanager-perl libparams-validate-perl
  libparse-recdescent-perl libperlio-utf8-strict-perl libphonon4qt5-4
  libplacebo4 libprotobuf-lite10 libproxy-tools libqca-qt5-2
  libqca-qt5-2-plugins libqt5quickcontrols2-5 libqt5quicktemplates2-5
  libqt5texttospeech5 libregexp-common-perl libresid-builder0c2a
  libsdl-image1.2 libsidplay2 libsort-key-perl libssh2-1 libtext-bibtex-perl
  libtext-csv-perl libtext-csv-xs-perl libtext-glob-perl libtext-roman-perl
  libtie-cycle-perl libupnp6 libusageenvironment3 libvoikko1 libxcb-composite0
  libxml-libxml-simple-perl libxml-libxslt-perl libxml-writer-perl
  linux-headers-5.3.0-26 linux-headers-5.3.0-26-generic
  linux-image-5.3.0-26-generic linux-modules-5.3.0-26-generic melt
  python3-blinker python3-jwt python3-oauthlib python3-requests-oauthlib
  qml-module-qtquick-controls2 qml-module-qtquick-templates2
  qtspeech5-flite-plugin sonnet-plugins swh-plugins texlive-bibtex-extra
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

And by running the **apt autoremove** i get this output:

```
so@so-notebook:~$ sudo apt autoremove
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  biber catdoc dvdauthor kactivities-bin kbibtex-data kde-cli-tools-data kded5
  kdenlive-data kpackagetool5 libaribb24-0 libautovivification-perl
  libbasicusageenvironment1 libbtparse2 libbusiness-isbn-data-perl
  libbusiness-isbn-perl libbusiness-ismn-perl libbusiness-issn-perl libcddb2
  libclass-factory-util-perl libclass-inspector-perl libclass-singleton-perl
  libdata-compare-perl libdata-uniqid-perl libdate-simple-perl
  libdatetime-calendar-julian-perl libdatetime-format-builder-perl
  libdatetime-format-strptime-perl libdatetime-locale-perl libdatetime-perl
  libdatetime-timezone-perl libdbusmenu-qt5-2 libdvbpsi10
  libencode-eucjpms-perl libencode-jis2k-perl libepub0 libfakekey0
  libfile-find-rule-perl libfile-sharedir-perl libfile-slurper-perl
  libgroupsock8 libhfstospell9 libipc-run3-perl libkf5activities5
  libkf5attica5 libkf5bookmarks-data libkf5bookmarks5 libkf5completion-data
  libkf5completion5 libkf5crash5 libkf5dbusaddons-bin libkf5dbusaddons-data
  libkf5dbusaddons5 libkf5declarative-data libkf5doctools5
  libkf5filemetadata-bin libkf5filemetadata-data libkf5filemetadata3
  libkf5globalaccel-bin libkf5globalaccel-data libkf5globalaccel5
  libkf5globalaccelprivate5 libkf5jobwidgets-data libkf5jobwidgets5
  libkf5kcmutils-data libkf5kiocore5 libkf5kiofilewidgets5 libkf5kiontlm5
  libkf5kiowidgets5 libkf5kirigami2-5 libkf5newstuff-data
  libkf5notifications-data libkf5notifyconfig-data libkf5package-data
  libkf5package5 libkf5parts-data libkf5pty-data libkf5pty5 libkf5service-bin
  libkf5service-data libkf5service5 libkf5solid5 libkf5solid5-data
  libkf5sonnet5-data libkf5sonnetcore5 libkf5sonnetui5 libkf5su-bin
  libkf5su-data libkf5su5 libkf5textwidgets-data libkf5textwidgets5
  libkf5wallet-data libkf5xmlgui-bin libkf5xmlgui-data libkf5xmlgui5
  liblingua-translit-perl liblist-allutils-perl liblist-someutils-perl
  liblist-utilsby-perl liblivemedia62 libmicrodns0 libnfs11
  libnumber-compare-perl libopenmpt-modplug1
  libpackage-deprecationmanager-perl libparams-validate-perl
  libparse-recdescent-perl libperlio-utf8-strict-perl libphonon4qt5-4
  libplacebo4 libprotobuf-lite10 libproxy-tools libqca-qt5-2
  libqca-qt5-2-plugins libqt5quickcontrols2-5 libqt5quicktemplates2-5
  libqt5texttospeech5 libregexp-common-perl libresid-builder0c2a
  libsdl-image1.2 libsidplay2 libsort-key-perl libssh2-1 libtext-bibtex-perl
  libtext-csv-perl libtext-csv-xs-perl libtext-glob-perl libtext-roman-perl
  libtie-cycle-perl libupnp6 libusageenvironment3 libvoikko1 libxcb-composite0
  libxml-libxml-simple-perl libxml-libxslt-perl libxml-writer-perl
  linux-headers-5.3.0-26 linux-headers-5.3.0-26-generic
  linux-image-5.3.0-26-generic linux-modules-5.3.0-26-generic melt
  python3-blinker python3-jwt python3-oauthlib python3-requests-oauthlib
  qml-module-qtquick-controls2 qml-module-qtquick-templates2
  qtspeech5-flite-plugin sonnet-plugins swh-plugins texlive-bibtex-extra
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 150 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
After this operation, 419 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 496211 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing biber (2.14-1~18.04.york0) ...
Removing libkf5filemetadata-bin:amd64 (5.44.0-0ubuntu1) ...
Removing catdoc (1:0.95-4.1) ...
Removing dvdauthor (0.7.0-2build1) ...
Removing kactivities-bin (5.44.0-0ubuntu1) ...
Removing kbibtex-data (0.8~20170819git31a77b27e8e83836e-3build2) ...
Removing kde-cli-tools-data (4:5.12.8-0ubuntu0.1) ...
Removing kded5 (5.44.0-0ubuntu1) ...
Removing kdenlive-data (4:17.12.3-0ubuntu1) ...
Removing kpackagetool5 (5.44.0-0ubuntu1) ...
Removing libaribb24-0:amd64 (1.0.3-1) ...
Removing libautovivification-perl (0.17-1build1) ...
Removing libbasicusageenvironment1:amd64 (2018.02.18-1) ...
Removing libtext-bibtex-perl (0.88-3~18.04.york0) ...
Removing libbtparse2 (0.88-3~18.04.york0) ...
Removing libbusiness-isbn-perl (3.004-1) ...
Removing libbusiness-isbn-data-perl (20140910.003-1) ...
Removing libbusiness-ismn-perl (1.131-1) ...
Removing libbusiness-issn-perl (1.002-1) ...
Removing libcddb2 (1.3.2-5fakesync1) ...
Removing libdatetime-format-builder-perl (0.8100-1) ...
Removing libclass-factory-util-perl (1.7-3) ...
Removing libdatetime-format-strptime-perl (1.7500-1) ...
Removing libdatetime-calendar-julian-perl (0.04-1) ...
Removing libdatetime-perl (2:1.46-1) ...
Removing libdatetime-locale-perl (1:1.17-1) ...
Removing libfile-sharedir-perl (1.104-1) ...
Removing libclass-inspector-perl (1.32-1) ...
Removing libdatetime-timezone-perl (1:2.18-1+2018d) ...
Removing libclass-singleton-perl (1.5-1) ...
Removing libdata-compare-perl (1.25-1) ...
Removing libdata-uniqid-perl (0.12-1) ...
Removing libdate-simple-perl (3.0300-1build4) ...
Removing libdbusmenu-qt5-2:amd64 (0.9.3+16.04.20160218-1ubuntu1) ...
Removing libdvbpsi10:amd64 (1.3.2-1) ...
Removing libencode-eucjpms-perl (0.07-3build5) ...
Removing libencode-jis2k-perl (0.03-1build3) ...
Removing libepub0 (0.2.2-4ubuntu1) ...
Removing libfakekey0:amd64 (0.1-9) ...
Removing libfile-find-rule-perl (0.34-1) ...
Removing libfile-slurper-perl (0.011-1) ...
Removing libgroupsock8:amd64 (2018.02.18-1) ...
Removing sonnet-plugins (5.44.0-0ubuntu1) ...
Removing libvoikko1:amd64 (4.1.1-1.1) ...
Removing libhfstospell9:amd64 (0.4.5~r343-2.1build2) ...
Removing libipc-run3-perl (0.048-1) ...
Removing libkf5activities5:amd64 (5.44.0-0ubuntu1) ...
Removing libkf5kiofilewidgets5:amd64 (5.44.0-0ubuntu1) ...
Removing libkf5bookmarks5:amd64 (5.44.0-0ubuntu1) ...
Removing libkf5xmlgui5:amd64 (5.44.0-0ubuntu2) ...
Removing libkf5attica5:amd64 (5.44.0-0ubuntu1) ...
Removing libkf5bookmarks-data (5.44.0-0ubuntu1) ...
Removing libkf5textwidgets5:amd64 (5.44.0-0ubuntu1) ...
Removing libkf5kiowidgets5:amd64 (5.44.0-0ubuntu1) ...
Removing libkf5completion5:amd64 (5.44.0-0ubuntu1) ...
Removing libkf5completion-data (5.44.0-0ubuntu1) ...
Removing libkf5su-bin (5.44.0-0ubuntu1) ...
Removing libkf5su5:amd64 (5.44.0-0ubuntu1) ...
Removing libkf5kiocore5:amd64 (5.44.0-0ubuntu1) ...
Removing libkf5service-bin (5.44.0-0ubuntu1) ...
Removing libkf5globalaccel-bin (5.44.0-0ubuntu1) ...
Removing libkf5crash5:amd64 (5.44.0-0ubuntu1) ...
Removing libkf5dbusaddons-bin (5.44.0-0ubuntu1) ...
Removing libkf5service5:amd64 (5.44.0-0ubuntu1) ...
Removing libkf5dbusaddons5:amd64 (5.44.0-0ubuntu1) ...
Removing libkf5dbusaddons-data (5.44.0-0ubuntu1) ...
Removing libkf5declarative-data (5.44.0-0ubuntu3) ...
Removing libkf5doctools5:amd64 (5.44.0-0ubuntu1) ...
Removing libkf5filemetadata3:amd64 (5.44.0-0ubuntu1) ...
Removing libkf5filemetadata-data (5.44.0-0ubuntu1) ...
Removing libkf5globalaccelprivate5:amd64 (5.44.0-0ubuntu1) ...
Removing libkf5globalaccel5:amd64 (5.44.0-0ubuntu1) ...
Removing libkf5globalaccel-data (5.44.0-0ubuntu1) ...
Removing libkf5jobwidgets5:amd64 (5.44.0-0ubuntu1) ...
Removing libkf5jobwidgets-data (5.44.0-0ubuntu1) ...
Removing libkf5kcmutils-data (5.44.0-0ubuntu1) ...
Removing libkf5kiontlm5:amd64 (5.44.0-0ubuntu1) ...
Removing libkf5kirigami2-5 (5.44.0-0ubuntu1) ...
Removing libkf5newstuff-data (5.44.0-0ubuntu1) ...
Removing libkf5notifications-data (5.44.0-0ubuntu1) ...
Removing libkf5notifyconfig-data (5.44.0-0ubuntu1) ...
Removing libkf5package5:amd64 (5.44.0-0ubuntu1) ...
Removing libkf5package-data (5.44.0-0ubuntu1) ...
Removing libkf5parts-data (5.44.0-0ubuntu1) ...
Removing libkf5pty5:amd64 (5.44.0-0ubuntu1) ...
Removing libkf5pty-data (5.44.0-0ubuntu1) ...
Removing libkf5service-data (5.44.0-0ubuntu1) ...
Removing libkf5solid5:amd64 (5.44.0-0ubuntu1) ...
Removing libkf5solid5-data (5.44.0-0ubuntu1) ...
Removing libkf5sonnetui5:amd64 (5.44.0-0ubuntu1) ...
Removing libkf5sonnetcore5:amd64 (5.44.0-0ubuntu1) ...
Removing libkf5sonnet5-data (5.44.0-0ubuntu1) ...
Removing libkf5su-data (5.44.0-0ubuntu1) ...
Removing libkf5textwidgets-data (5.44.0-0ubuntu1) ...
Removing libkf5wallet-data (5.44.0-0ubuntu1) ...
Removing libkf5xmlgui-bin (5.44.0-0ubuntu2) ...
Removing libkf5xmlgui-data (5.44.0-0ubuntu2) ...
Removing liblingua-translit-perl (0.28-1) ...
Removing liblist-allutils-perl (0.14-1) ...
Removing liblist-someutils-perl (0.56-1) ...
Removing liblist-utilsby-perl (0.10-1) ...
Removing liblivemedia62:amd64 (2018.02.18-1) ...
Removing libmicrodns0:amd64 (0.0.8-1) ...
Removing libnfs11:amd64 (2.0.0-1~exp1) ...
Removing libnumber-compare-perl (0.03-1) ...
Removing libopenmpt-modplug1:amd64 (0.3.11-1~bionic) ...
Removing libpackage-deprecationmanager-perl (0.17-1) ...
Removing libparams-validate-perl (1.29-1) ...
Removing libparse-recdescent-perl (1.967015+dfsg-2) ...
Removing libperlio-utf8-strict-perl (0.007-2) ...
Removing libphonon4qt5-4:amd64 (4:4.10.0-2) ...
Removing libplacebo4:amd64 (0.4.0-2) ...
Removing libprotobuf-lite10:amd64 (3.0.0-9.1ubuntu1) ...
Removing libproxy-tools (0.4.15-1) ...
Removing libqca-qt5-2-plugins:amd64 (2.1.3-2ubuntu2) ...
Removing libqca-qt5-2:amd64 (2.1.3-2ubuntu2) ...
Removing qml-module-qtquick-controls2:amd64 (5.9.5-0ubuntu2) ...
Removing libqt5quickcontrols2-5:amd64 (5.9.5-0ubuntu2) ...
Removing qml-module-qtquick-templates2:amd64 (5.9.5-0ubuntu2) ...
Removing libqt5quicktemplates2-5:amd64 (5.9.5-0ubuntu2) ...
Removing qtspeech5-flite-plugin:amd64 (5.9.5-0ubuntu1) ...
Removing libqt5texttospeech5:amd64 (5.9.5-0ubuntu1) ...
Removing libregexp-common-perl (2017060201-1) ...
Removing libresid-builder0c2a (2.1.1-15ubuntu1) ...
Removing libsdl-image1.2:amd64 (1.2.12-8ubuntu0.1) ...
Removing libsidplay2 (2.1.1-15ubuntu1) ...
Removing libsort-key-perl (1.33-2) ...
Removing libssh2-1:amd64 (1.8.0-1) ...
Removing libtext-csv-perl (1.95-1) ...
Removing libtext-csv-xs-perl (1.34-1) ...
Removing libtext-glob-perl (0.10-1) ...
Removing libtext-roman-perl (3.5-2) ...
Removing libtie-cycle-perl (1.225-1) ...
Removing libupnp6:amd64 (1:1.6.24-4) ...
Removing libusageenvironment3:amd64 (2018.02.18-1) ...
Removing libxcb-composite0:amd64 (1.13-2~ubuntu18.04) ...
Removing libxml-libxml-simple-perl (0.99-1) ...
Removing libxml-libxslt-perl (1.95-1build2) ...
Removing libxml-writer-perl (0.625-1) ...
Removing linux-headers-5.3.0-26-generic (5.3.0-26.28~18.04.1) ...
Removing linux-headers-5.3.0-26 (5.3.0-26.28~18.04.1) ...
Removing linux-image-5.3.0-26-generic (5.3.0-26.28~18.04.1) ...
/etc/kernel/prerm.d/dkms:
dkms: removing: virtualbox 5.2.34 (5.3.0-26-generic) (x86_64)

-------- Uninstall Beginning --------
Module:  virtualbox
Version: 5.2.34
Kernel:  5.3.0-26-generic (x86_64)
-------------------------------------

Status: Before uninstall, this module version was ACTIVE on this kernel.

vboxdrv.ko:
 - Uninstallation
   - Deleting from: /lib/modules/5.3.0-26-generic/updates/dkms/
 - Original module
   - No original module was found for this module on this kernel.
   - Use the dkms install command to reinstall any previous module version.


vboxnetadp.ko:
 - Uninstallation
   - Deleting from: /lib/modules/5.3.0-26-generic/updates/dkms/
 - Original module
   - No original module was found for this module on this kernel.
   - Use the dkms install command to reinstall any previous module version.


vboxnetflt.ko:
 - Uninstallation
   - Deleting from: /lib/modules/5.3.0-26-generic/updates/dkms/
 - Original module
   - No original module was found for this module on this kernel.
   - Use the dkms install command to reinstall any previous module version.


vboxpci.ko:
 - Uninstallation
   - Deleting from: /lib/modules/5.3.0-26-generic/updates/dkms/
 - Original module
   - No original module was found for this module on this kernel.
   - Use the dkms install command to reinstall any previous module version.

depmod...

DKMS: uninstall completed.
/etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools:
update-initramfs: Deleting /boot/initrd.img-5.3.0-26-generic
/etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub:
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.3.0-45-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.3.0-45-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.3.0-42-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.3.0-42-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-91-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-91-generic
Found Windows 8 on /dev/sda2
done
Removing linux-modules-5.3.0-26-generic (5.3.0-26.28~18.04.1) ...
Removing melt (6.6.0-1build1) ...
Removing python3-requests-oauthlib (0.8.0-0.1) ...
Removing python3-oauthlib (2.0.6-1) ...
Removing python3-blinker (1.4+dfsg1-0.1) ...
Removing python3-jwt (1.5.3+ds1-1) ...
Removing swh-plugins (0.4.17-2) ...
Removing texlive-bibtex-extra (2019.202000302-1~18.04.york0) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.60ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for menu (2.1.47ubuntu2.1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.27-3ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for doc-base (0.10.8) ...
Processing 1 removed doc-base file...
Registering documents with scrollkeeper...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.8.3-2ubuntu0.1) ...
Processing triggers for shared-mime-info (1.9-2) ...
Unknown media type in type 'chemical/x-alchemy'
Unknown media type in type 'chemical/x-cache'
Unknown media type in type 'chemical/x-cactvs-ascii'
Unknown media type in type 'chemical/x-cactvs-binary'
Unknown media type in type 'chemical/x-cactvs-table'
Unknown media type in type 'chemical/x-cdx'
Unknown media type in type 'chemical/x-cdxml'
Unknown media type in type 'chemical/x-chem3d'
Unknown media type in type 'chemical/x-cif'
Unknown media type in type 'chemical/x-cml'
Unknown media type in type 'chemical/x-daylight-smiles'
Unknown media type in type 'chemical/x-dmol'
Unknown media type in type 'chemical/x-gamess-input'
Unknown media type in type 'chemical/x-gamess-output'
Unknown media type in type 'chemical/x-gaussian-input'
Unknown media type in type 'chemical/x-gaussian-log'
Unknown media type in type 'chemical/x-genbank'
Unknown media type in type 'chemical/x-gulp'
Unknown media type in type 'chemical/x-hin'
Unknown media type in type 'chemical/x-inchi'
Unknown media type in type 'chemical/x-inchi-xml'
Unknown media type in type 'chemical/x-jcamp-dx'
Unknown media type in type 'chemical/x-macromodel-input'
Unknown media type in type 'chemical/x-mdl-molfile'
Unknown media type in type 'chemical/x-mdl-rdfile'
Unknown media type in type 'chemical/x-mdl-rxnfile'
Unknown media type in type 'chemical/x-mdl-sdfile'
Unknown media type in type 'chemical/x-mdl-tgf'
Unknown media type in type 'chemical/x-mmcif'
Unknown media type in type 'chemical/x-mol2'
Unknown media type in type 'chemical/x-mopac-graph'
Unknown media type in type 'chemical/x-mopac-input'
Unknown media type in type 'chemical/x-mopac-out'
Unknown media type in type 'chemical/x-msi-car'
Unknown media type in type 'chemical/x-msi-hessian'
Unknown media type in type 'chemical/x-msi-mdf'
Unknown media type in type 'chemical/x-msi-msi'
Unknown media type in type 'chemical/x-ncbi-asn1'
Unknown media type in type 'chemical/x-ncbi-asn1-binary'
Unknown media type in type 'chemical/x-ncbi-asn1-xml'
Unknown media type in type 'chemical/x-pdb'
Unknown media type in type 'chemical/x-shelx'
Unknown media type in type 'chemical/x-vmd'
Unknown media type in type 'chemical/x-xyz'
Unknown media type in type 'all/all'
Unknown media type in type 'all/allfiles'
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.17-2) ...
Processing triggers for tex-common (6.13-1~18.04) ...
Running mktexlsr. This may take some time... done.
```

but now by printing the vlc in terminal it works:

[image: ```]

So how did it happen?

Update:

I have tried **apt-get remove** and get this output:

```
so@so-notebook:~$ sudo apt-get remove vlc
[sudo] password for so: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package 'vlc' is not installed, so not removed
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
so@so-notebook:~$
```

Thanks.

Comment: Apt can ONLY install/remove deb packages. Looks like you installed VLC some other way. How you install software depends entirely upon how you originally installed it.

Comment: I don't remember maybe by Ubuntu Software center application.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does update-mime-database complain about uri/rtspt and other unusual types?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18806/why-does-update-mime-database-complain-about-uri-rtspt-and-other-unusual-types)

Comment: What is the output of `type -a vlc`?

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! Please [edit] the output of `which vlc` into your post. Thank you for helping us help you!

Answer (score 1):

You could probably installed vlc using snap or source files.

Run `vlc --version` to find out what is installed vlc version and find out what is the repository's version by command execution: `apt-cache policy vlc`

To remove snap's vlc use:

```
sudo snap remove vlc
```

To remove vlc installed using sources, then:

```
cd /path/to/vlc/sources/folder
sudo make uninstall
```

To find out where is that directory, use `find` command:

```
find ~/ -iname *vlc*
```